# Cannot connect to Postgresql running in docker with Host = localhost

Tags: postgresql, docker, ip

I have Postgresql running in a Docker container with port `5432` is exposed.

```
$ docker ps -a
IMAGE               STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
postgres:9.6        Up 32 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   service_postgresql_1
```

My IP address in LAN:

```
$ ifconfig | grep inet

...
inet 192.84.4.108 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.84.4.255
...
```

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

My OS: macOS High Sierra

My problems:
Failed to connect to Postgres with Host = localhost

`Host = 192.84.4.108` -> Success

`Host = localhost` -> Fail

I use both `pgAdmin 4` and `IntelliJ IDEA` and the results are the same.

Please let me know the cause if you faced a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: My Firewall is Off

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using Docker toolbox

From docs :

> Docker Desktop for Mac is available for free. 
>   Requires Apple Mac OS Sierra 10.12 or above. Download Docker Toolbox for previous OS versions.

Which version do you have? If you've installed Docker toolbox, that's a normal behavior